# jQuery Geocomplete - Remove Google Signature

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocomplete

I am using [jQuery Geocomplete](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) Library.

What I have done is this-

```js
$(function()
{
 $("#find_product_location").geocomplete(
 {
  map   : "#product_location",
  mapOptions :
  {
   mapTypeId : 'roadmap',  //roadmap, satellite,hybrid, terrain,
   scrollwheel : true,
   zoom: 10,
   center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.42152681633113, -119.27327880000001),
  },
  markerOptions:
  {
   draggable: true
  },
 });
 //var product_location_map = $("#find_product_location").geocomplete("map"); //Get the map for any more operation
});
```

```css
#product_location
{ 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.7.0/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>

<input id="find_product_location" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Address"/>
<div id="product_location"></div>
```

But I am getting this small google signature icon in the type-head-

[image]

Is there any way of removing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/issues/214:

> If you also show a Google Map, it is OK to hide the logo:
>
> https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/policies#logo_requirements
>
> You can hide it using CSS:
>
> ```
> .pac-container:after {  /* Disclaimer: not needed to show 'powered by Google' if also a Google Map is shown */
>     background-image: none !important;
>     height: 0px;
> }
> ```